# Two vectors equal in 3-D space

Tags: vectors, 3d

If $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c} \in \Delta^{3}$, prove that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}, \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \vec{a} \times \vec{c}$ and $\vec{a} \neq 0 \implies \vec{b} = \vec{c}$

I can't find a solution to this question. Can anyone help? Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is $\Delta^3$?

Comment: You need to be more specific — are you asking for two vectors that span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two identities can be written as 
$$
(b-c)\cdot a=0,\ \ \ \ (b-c)\times a=0. 
$$
The first equality says that $b-c$ is orthogonal to $a$. When two vectors are orthogonal to each other, the norm of their cross product is the product of their norms. So 
$$
0=\|(b-c)\times a\|=\|b-c\|\,\|a\|.
$$
If $a\ne0$, then $\|a\|>0$ and so $\|b-c\|=0$.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks a lot.